# Number of asterisks starting a C# comment block

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In a C# program in Visual Studio 2010 I have a large, multiline comment block starting with

> /**

Part way through the comment block is a line that looks like this . . .

> this.afIODisplay = "<" + lineToParse + Environment.NewLine +
>   this.afIODisplay;

At the point of the less-than symbol the color changes from comment-green to gray and the compiler issues a warning saying

> XML comment on 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' has badly formed XML -- 'A name was
>   started with an invalid character.'

(xxxx's replace proprietary code identifier)  **Why is the compiler trying to interpret the comment block as XML?**

As an experiment I tried escaping the less-than symbol with

> &lt

but that didn't fix it; it just replaced the warning with a new one saying

> A name was started with an invalid character

and eliminated the transition to gray.    I then replaced the starting line of the comment block with

> /*

and **the problem went away!!**    It also stayed gone with a whole line of asterisks.   Why do the number of asterisks matter in C# comments?   Or is this just a Visual Studio bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have malformed XML in a documentation comment. This generates a warning according the specification. In Appendix A of the C# 5 spec:

> Comments having a special form can be used to direct a tool to produce XML from those comments and the source code elements, which they precede. Such comments are single-line comments that start with three slashes (`///`), or delimited comments that start with a slash and two stars (`/**`).

and

> The text within documentation comments must be well formed according to the rules of XML (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml). If the XML is ill formed, a warning is generated and the documentation file will contain a comment saying that an error was encountered.

Answer (score 2):

multiline comment in c# starts with /*
/** is used for XML comments

Comment: XML comments use `///`

Comment: I thought XML comments were ///

Comment: @Servy an XML comment is allowed to have the single-line form with each line starting with `///`, or the multi-line form which starts with `/**`, ends with `*/`, and optionally includes a leading `*` at the beginning of each line other than the first.